# Unable to render JSON data in react component

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to parse some JSON from an Ajax call to display it a table using react datatable component. The problem which I am facing is that when I try to put the data in a state variable using set state method, I am not able to access the required data. This is what the JSON looks like:

```
{
  "Search": [
    {
      "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
      "Year": "1977",
      "imdbID": "tt0076759",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BOTIyMDY2NGQtOGJjNi00OTk4LWFhMDgtYmE3M2NiYzM0YTVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTU1NTcwOTk@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
      "Year": "1980",
      "imdbID": "tt0080684",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE2MzQwMTgxN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDQzNjk2OQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi",
      "Year": "1983",
      "imdbID": "tt0086190",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ0MzI1NjYwOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODU3NDU2MTE@._V1._CR93,97,1209,1861_SX89_AL_.jpg_V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Star Wars: The Force Awakens",
      "Year": "2015",
      "imdbID": "tt2488496",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BOTAzODEzNDAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU1MTgzNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace",
      "Year": "1999",
      "imdbID": "tt0120915",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ4NjEwNDA2Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDUyNDQzNw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith",
      "Year": "2005",
      "imdbID": "tt0121766",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTc4MTc3NTQ5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTg0NjI4NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Star Trek",
      "Year": "2009",
      "imdbID": "tt0796366",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE5NDQ5OTE4Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTE3NDIzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones",
      "Year": "2002",
      "imdbID": "tt0121765",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTY5MjI5NTIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMTM1Njg2._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Star Trek Into Darkness",
      "Year": "2013",
      "imdbID": "tt1408101",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk2NzczOTgxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODQ5ODczOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Star Trek: First Contact",
      "Year": "1996",
      "imdbID": "tt0117731",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4OTYwODY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTg2NjIyMDE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "totalResults": "2846",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

"data.Search" should gives me an array of objects. This is not being sent to the data table component. Instead, if I try to somehow display "data.totalResults" it works because it throws single value. Or if the same array of objects is sent thru a local variable, it works. Please help me as I am new to React and this really is taking a lot of time! Any help appreciated in advance!

```
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">

var tableColumns = [
   { 'title': 'Title', 'prop': 'Title' },
   { 'title': 'Year', 'prop': 'Year' }
 ];

var destination = document.querySelector("#container");
var Buildrules = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: {}};
      },

  loadData: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star&r=json&plot=short',
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({data: data});
        console.log(this.state.data.Search);
      }.bind(this)
    })

  },

componentWillMount: function(){
  this.loadData();

},
componentDidMount:function(){

},
render:function(){

  return (
    React.createElement(ReactDataComponents.DataTable, {
      keys: 'id',
      columns: this.props.col,
      initialData: this.state.data.Search, //Here, "data.Search" should give an array of objects but i am facing issue. If the same data is fed using a local variable, it works!
      initialPageLength: 5,
      initialSortBy: { prop: 'Title', order: 'descending'}
    })

        );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <div id="blah">
    <Buildrules col = {tableColumns} />
  </div>,
  destination
);


</script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/fpfuuchj/1/

There are a few things that you have missed:

- when you log your result the first time, it is `undefined` because you perform async request to fetch the data. This is why you need to check if its present and only then render it.
- Also you log like `console.log("this.state.data.Search"` + this.state.data.Search). It should be: `console.log("this.state.data.Search", this.state.data.Search)`
- Once data is there, you can see your search result
- (Optional) Please bear in mind that Ajax requests are performed in `componentDidMount` as suggested in [react's docu](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html)

---

If you don't want to display the data, but pass it to a DataTable component, instead of

```
const searches = this.state.data.Search ? this.state.data.Search.map((searchResult, index) => <h1 key={index}> {searchResult.Title} </h1>) : ""
```

simply have

```
const searches = this.state.data.Search ? this.state.data.Search.map(searchResult => <DataTable tableColumns={searchResult} />) : ""
```

This will display your `<DataTable />` components once data is fetched.

Comment: Thanks Leo.. i added the JSON.parse. But still the problem exists. it says " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle so I can have a look?

Comment: Hi Leo. I just created a simple fiddle to access the array of objects in render method. https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/55546/ .Note the output of the console log in that method. It gives undefined always.

Comment: hi chakri, please have a look at my updated answer and thanks for your effort to create jsfiddle - it helped me a lot to understand your problem.

Comment: My idea here is not to display the array as it is in the render method. Instead, I need to pass it to datatable as an input. Similar example can be found here in this link https://jsbin.com/ziyawu/9/edit?js,output . But here, i would pass the data from an AJAX call. Hope I am making some sense in my question. :)

Comment: Thanks Leo for the patience in answering my question. great.:). But I am still not able to render. My problem here could be that the render method is calling data table by the time ajax call fetches data as you said. I tried to do some changes with your suggestions in mind. Please have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/gm4ur5sb/ . Help me with corrections please.

Comment: Hi Leo, I tried some changes in render method to deal with the async calls. I placed the render part in if else blocks. It worked. Pls let me know if this is ok or suggest any correct method

   if(this.state.data.Search)
   {
     return (
    React.createElement(ReactDataComponents.DataTable, {
      keys: 'id',
      columns: this.props.col,
      initialData: this.state.data.Search,
      initialPageLength: 5,
      initialSortBy: { prop: 'Title', order: 'descending'}
    })
    );
   }
   else {
     return (
    <h2>Please wait while loading!!!</h2>
     )
   }